# Why is the rate of a reaction always positive and why?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

Why rate of reaction can never be negative? And why rate is an experimental derived expression?

Comment: Otherwise you could not call it a reaction.

Answer (score 4):

No mystery. Chemists write equations so that reactants (on the left) yield products (on the right). So:
$$\ce{H2O -> H^+ + OH^-}$$
and
$$\ce{H^+ + OH^- -> H2O}$$

The reactions are read from left to right and reactivity is defined as positive from left to right - this means the reactivity for the reaction we want to look at is always positive. (great clarification from user *Stian Yttervik*.

Comment: I'd include the sentence *"The reactions are read from left to right and reactivity is defined as positive from left to right - this means the reactivity for the reaction we want to look at is always positive"*

Answer (score 3):

In a first order reaction such as a *cis*-*trans* isomerization or decay of an excited state the rate is

$$\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{C}]}{\mathrm dt} = -k[\ce{C}],\tag{1}$$

so is negative, but the rate constant $k$ is always positive. The negative sign is because the initial species $\ce{C}$ decays away in time. Integrating this expression leads to exponential kinetics. If $\ce{C}$ decays into a product $\ce{P},$ then

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{P}]}{\mathrm dt} = +k[\ce{C}].\tag{2}$$

The rate constant is determined experimentally as it us usually impossible to calculate what it will be. Similarly, the actual mechanism of a reaction is not always what the stoichiometry would indicate, in fact it is usually not and so has to be determined experimentally.